# Should we use Jquery with react? What are pros and cons

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, reactjs, jquery-ui

I am not sure about using Jquery with react as some of the post showing that it can have unexpected results as reactJS operate on Virtual Dom while Jquery is on real dom. Can anybody tell me what are the advantage and disadvantage of using reactjs with Jquery. What about proformance?

Comment: I think this link will help you https://hashnode.com/post/why-is-it-a-bad-idea-to-mix-jquery-and-react-cit77t20z02j5fq536wlyiwtk

Answer (score 3):

React can do everything jQuery can, so it's not recommended to use jQuery inside a React application. React will create the DOM dynamically, whereas jQuery acts upon the existent DOM. If you need direct access to a DOM node within React, you can use [`refs`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).